# Inject ads in WordPress archive

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

The code below is used to inject Ads banner after the 5th post on wordpress archive page, i would like to inject banner after the 1st and 5th post but i have no idea how to modify the code to work for what i need it for.

```
<?php
function insert_between_posts( $post ) {
    global $wp_query;

    // Check if we're in the main loop
    if ( $wp_query->post != $post )
        return;

    // Check if we're at the right position
    if ( 5 != $wp_query->current_post )
        return;

    // Display the banner
    echo '
    <div banner>BANNER</div>
    ';
    }
   add_action( 'the_post', 'insert_between_posts' );
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change

```
if ( 5 != $wp_query->current_post )
```

with

```
if ( 5 % $wp_query->current_post == 0 || 1 != $wp_query->current_post)
```

My code would display the banner everytime the "current_post" is a multiple of 5, or is equal to 1